# html email text center vertically in div

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email, text-align

i am trying to center the text in a div in an html email. In Browserview everything is ok with line-height. But in apple mail and in outlook it isn't vertically centered.

```html
 <div style='width: 80%; margin: auto; position: relative;'>
            <div style='height: 40px; margin-bottom: 2px; background-color: rgb(68, 228, 60); float: left; width: 60%;'></div>
            <div style='height: 40px; margin-bottom: 2px; background-color: rgb(227, 243, 121); float: left; width: 20%; text-align: left;'></div>
            <div style='height: 40px; margin-bottom: 2px; background-color: rgb(236, 74, 16); float: left; width: 20%; text-align: left; border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;'></div>
            <div style='border-style: solid; border-width: 0px 1px 0px 0px; border-color: black; position: absolute; height: 40px; margin-bottom: 2px; background-color: rgba(13, 12, 11, 0.330); width: 30%; text-align: right; font-weight: 600; font-family: 'Verdana', Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; line-height: 40px; vertical-align: middle; border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;'>30%&nbsp&nbsp</div>
    </div>
```

```
<table style="width: 80%; margin: auto; position: relative;">
        <td style="vertical-align: middle; height: 40px; margin-bottom: 2px; background-color: rgb(68, 228, 60); float: left; width: 60%;"></td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle; height: 40px; margin-bottom: 2px; background-color: rgb(227, 243, 121); float: left; width: 20%; text-align: left;"></td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle; height: 40px; margin-bottom: 2px; background-color: rgb(236, 74, 16); float: left; width: 20%; text-align: left; border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;"></td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle; border-style: solid; border-width: 0px 1px 0px 0px; border-color: black; position: absolute; height: 40px; margin-bottom: 2px; background-color: rgba(13, 12, 11, 0.330); 
            width: 35%; text-align: right; font-weight: 600; font-family: 'Verdana', Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;">35%&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    </table>
```

also tried with the table snippet...don't get it.

How can i achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: Your style tag is with single quotes and font family declaration is single as well. Change all the styles to be in double quote and try it.

Comment: @Syfer copied the code from the php file.

Comment: So you are not able to change it? You will have a lot of issues with emails if you ware not able to. You will need to use ghost tables or ghost columns if you stick to div's only.

Comment: @Syfer in the php i need single quotes... i am not a professional, so i only want to know how i can change the code to work in outlook and other mail clients. For Browser i did by myself and it works.

Comment: try escaping the single quotes inside the single quotes like: `<div style='border-style: solid; border-width: 0px 1px 0px 0px; border-color: black; position: absolute; height: 40px; margin-bottom: 2px; background-color: rgba(13, 12, 11, 0.330); width: 30%; text-align: right; font-weight: 600; font-family: \'Verdana\', Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; line-height: 40px; vertical-align: middle; border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;'>30%&nbsp&nbsp</div>`

Comment: nope, thats not the problem. i try the html code seperated in my browser before i copy it to the php file.

Comment: It did fix it for me. Its up to you though but since you are attempting emails, can I suggest you stick to `tables`? They have universal support. Outlooks specially don't like `div`'s that much.

Comment: @Syfer what did fix it? The single quotes or switching to tables? Can you please show me a table version of my code? Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252934/discussion-between-syfer-and-d-schall).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of div use table component and it will work across the browser.

Comment: i also tried with the table snippet above, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: `<div style="width: 500px"><table style="width: 100%;"><tbody style="width: 100%;">
        <tr style="width: 100%; height: 140px">
            <td style="width: 25%;background-color: rgb(68, 228, 60);"></td>
            <td style="width: 25%;background-color: rgb(227, 243, 121); "></td>
            <td style="width: 25%;background-color: rgb(236, 74, 16); "></td>
            <td style="width: 25%;background-color: rgb(232, 74, 16);font-family: 'Verdana', Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;">35%&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr>
    </tbody> </table></div>
`

Comment: [Table](https://lembdadev.com/posts/create-a-table-using-object-oriented-javascript) is default aligned middle vertically

Comment: thank you, but last td should be over the other three. in my demo code you can see position: relative and in the last child div position: absolute. last child is with transparent color to overlay the other ones. is this also possible with table?

Comment: Please [edit] the post to contain that code. It's difficult to read as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

To vertically center the text in the div, you can use the "display: table" and "display: table-cell" CSS properties.

By adding display: table-cell to the inner div, it becomes a table cell, and you can then use the vertical-align: middle property to center its contents vertically.

Additionally, you need to wrap the text inside another nested div with display: table and display: table-cell to vertically center it.

Also, I noticed that you have a missing semicolon after the `&nbsp;`.

This should work in most email clients, including Apple Mail and Outlook.